# Adding a new child object to an existing object in firebase using angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have users data stored in firebase as

```
users : {
    -KamJGmnL8S4Nn_okIcc : {
        name: "Someone",
        email: "example.com",
        website: "somesite.com"
    },
    -laeghmnw8S4Nn_9inb47 : {
        name: "Someone",
        email: "example.com",
        website: "somesite.com"
    }
}
```

I need to add a new Object `{ collections: <key> : { ... }, <key>: { ... } }` to an user, say the first user in the above object. I need to be able to push to `collections` as it can have several objects.

How can i do this with angularfire2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `list` to [push](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#saving-data) them individually:

```ts
const uid = "-KamJGmnL8S4Nn_okIcc";
const list = angularFire.database.list(`users/${uid}/collections`);
list.push({ name: "collection-a" });
list.push({ name: "collection-b" });
```

Or you could use an `object` to [update](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#saving-data) them together (in a multi-location update):

```ts
const uid = "-KamJGmnL8S4Nn_okIcc";
const obj = angularFire.database.object(`users/${uid}`);

let collections = {
    `collections/${obj.$ref.push()}/name`: "collection-a",
    `collections/${obj.$ref.push()}/name`: "collection-b",
};
obj.update(collections);
```

Note that push keys are generated on the client and you can generate one by calling `push` with no arguments.